# adding multiple background images in css

Tags: html, css, background-image, inline

I have a menu bar, and I am trying to attach two images to it
This is what I did-

```
background:url('images/bgs/bg_container_top_left.png') no-repeat top left ,url('images/bgs/bg_container_top_center.png') no-repeat top right;
```

How can I assign different properties to different images attached here?
Like if I want to give margin to first image

```
margin-left:-10px;
```

and to second image

```
 margin-left:-5px;
```

Comment: Instead of margin, you can try this background-position:0 0 0 -10px, 0 0 0 -5px; may be it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to position the images than change theses propertites

example:

```
background:url('images/bgs/bg_container_top_left.png') no-repeat top -10px ,url('images/bgs/bg_container_top_center.png') no-repeat top -5px;
```

or use `background-position: 0px 0px 0px 10px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div{background: url('http://blog.agilebits.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/time-machine-icon.png') -5px top no-repeat, url('http://aux3.iconpedia.net/uploads/69290979.png') -10px top no-repeat ; }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ygnk/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 allows for multiple background images to be used.  The format used is what you have shown in your first part.

```
background: url('images/bgs/bg_container_top_left.png') left top no-repeat,
            url('images/bgs/bg_container_top_center.png') right top no-repeat;
```

Rather than using margin, which I have a suspicion may not work (you can test it yourself if you like), I would suggest using the background-position property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/background-position) to adjust the starting position for each background.  If the actual margin for each element is different, you may want to think of creating separate elements for each background.  You could try using this code:

```
margin-left: -10px, -5px;
```

This follows the same format (listing background property value 1 first, and value 2 second), but I'm not sure if this is supported.